# hadoop hbase mapreduce combiner

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Now I am writing a Java program to write the output into HBase using Hadoop MapReduce. The question is about the Combiner class. Because now my reduce class extends TableReducer, instead of Reducer. So what about my combiner class, should it also extends TableReducer, or still extends Reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combiner class should extend the TableReducer itself and not Reducer.